# strncpy() segmentation fault (again)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strncpy

*I am trying to write a word formatting program that takes a data file, and formats it so that there are up to a certain amount of characters per line. I am encountering a segmentation fault error as I try to loop through the words in each line of the file.*

```
int readFile(  )
{
    int rc = 1;
    char readBuffer[ 256 ];
    char writeLine[ 256 ];
    char *word = malloc( numChars * sizeof( char ) );
    
    writeFile = fopen( writeName, "a" );
    
    if ( ( openFile = fopen( readName, "r" ) ) == NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "Unable to open %s file for read\n", readName );
        rc = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {       
        while( fgets( readBuffer, sizeof( readBuffer ), openFile) != NULL ) 
        {
            strncpy( writeLine, "", 0 );
            if ( readBuffer[0] != EOF ) 
            {
                strncpy( word, strtok( readBuffer, " " ), numChars -1 );
                while( word != NULL )
                {
                    if( strlen( word ) + strlen( writeLine ) < numChars )
                    {   
                        strcat( writeLine, word );
```

*I get the error here:*

```
                        strncpy( word, strtok( NULL, " " ), numChars -1 );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf( writeFile, "%s", writeLine );
                        strcpy( writeLine, word );
                        strncpy( word, strtok( NULL, " " ), numChars -1 );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return rc;
}
```

*I don't understand why this is happening. Isn't the point of strncpy that you tell it exactly how many characters to copy? If I specifically tell it only to copy chars up to one below the length of the string, why would there be a segmentation fault?
EDIT: I have revised the code to the following:*

```
            strcpy( writeLine, strtok( readBuffer, " " ) );
            
            while( strcpy( word, strtok( NULL, " " ) ) != NULL )
            {
                if( strlen( word ) + strlen( writeLine ) < numChars )
                {   
                    strcat( writeLine, word );
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf( writeFile, "%s", writeLine );
                    strcpy( writeLine, word );
                }
            }
```

*This gives no change in the operation, it's still a segmentation fault. How do I check that the token is valid and still access the same token if it is?*

---

#### Solved

I developed a solution that works:

```
    writeLine[0] = '\0';
    
    while( fgets( readBuffer, sizeof( readBuffer ), openFile) != NULL ) 
    {
        if ( readBuffer[0] != EOF ) 
        {               
            for( word = readBuffer; NULL != ( word = strtok( word, " \t\n" ) ); word=NULL )
            {
                printf("%s\n", writeLine );
                if( strlen( word ) + strlen( writeLine ) < numChars )
                {   
                    strcat( writeLine, word );
                    strcat( writeLine, " " );
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%s", "print\n");
                    fprintf( writeFile, "%s\n", writeLine );
                    strcpy( writeLine, word );
                    strcat( writeLine, " " );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf( writeFile, "%s\n", writeLine );
```

Comment: strtok is returning NULL

Comment: Could you explain why it would be returning NULL and what might be done to get around it?

Comment: strtok returns NULL once it reaches the end of the buffer.  You need to check its return value before passing it strncpy.   Also your while loop is wrong since word will never be NULL.  Your loop should loop until the return value of strtok is NULL.

Comment: What is `strncpy( writeLine, "", 0 );` supposed to accomplish?  It appears to do nothing.

Comment: @shf301, would I do something like while( word = strtok... ) then?

chux, I'm setting writeLine to empty, so I can append onto it with my loop.

Comment: @thephfactor I do not think that works.  Simply `writeLine[0] = '\0';`

Comment: @shf301 how would I check for strtok's value and still access the value later, without using strncpy() which is giving me the error now?

Comment: @thephfactor yes while(word = strtok...) will work

Comment: `if (readBuffer[0] != EOF )` is not sensible.  When the end-of-file condition occurs, `readBuffer[0]` does not take on a special value and certainly not `EOF`.

Comment: @shf301, but I cant assign strings in that way, can I? That's why Im using strncpy

Comment: word isn't a string it's a pointer you can assign pointers.  strtok returns a pointer into the string it is parsing so there isn't any need to make a copy.

Comment: @shf301 could you demonstrate what you mean, I think I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy()` does not null terminate if the number of characters in the limit is reached.  You need to null terminate yourself.  That makes the statement `strncpy( writeline, "", 0 );` do nothing (not even terminate the string).  Then you add onto that uninitialized string and it will go badly.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the point of strncpy that you tell it exactly how many characters to copy?

NO. The point of it is that you tell it how big a buffer you have available.  Then it copies as many characters as it can into that buffer (zeroing the rest), and it doesn't null-terminate if there were at least as many characters available as the buffer size.

Personally I never use it; alternatives which do actually always generate a string include `strcpy`, `sprintf`, `snprintf`,  or `memcpy` along with manually appending a null terminator.

Reading the documentation for standard functions is always advisable. `strncpy( writeline, "", 0 );` does nothing.